# Xamarin Forms Plugin.BLE Can't find any devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I wanted to write a simple application that sends bits to a bluetooth device. Currently I don't know what is wrong and I don't know where I got the bug.
I've got all permissions and i am asking for them (only localization showing up on screen)

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I am using [Plugin.BLE NuGet package](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le). The `StateChangedEvent` works just fine. However when I scan no devices are found (even though I have devices available for discovery).

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        IBluetoothLE ble;
        IAdapter adapter;
        ...
    }
    public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ble = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
            adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
            Devices = new ObservableCollection<Device_bluetooth>();
            ble.StateChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                labelTest.Text=($"The bluetooth state changed to {e.NewState}");
                DisplayAlert("Notice", e.NewState.ToString(), "OK !");
            };
        }
```

The function for scanning to discover devices below:

```
// Issue is here
        private async void ScanAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                Devices.Clear();
                adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
                {
                    Devices.Add(new Device_bluetooth() { Device = a.Device, Name = "Name: " + a.Device.Name.ToString(), Uuid = "UUID:" + a.Device.Id.ToString() });
                };

                if (!ble.Adapter.IsScanning)
                {
                    await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Notice", ex.Message.ToString(), "Error !");
            }
```

`Device_bluetooth` is my class for for storing devices, and I am showing them in a ListView like below:

```
        <ListView x:Name="mylistview" ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Height="100">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame  BackgroundColor="White"
                              HasShadow="true">
                                <StackLayout HeightRequest="100">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name ,Mode=TwoWay}"   />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Uuid ,Mode=TwoWay}"   />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Please help. I have tried almost everything and I cannot cope with it.

Comment: Did you request the location permission?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes i request the location permission by Xamarin.Essentials

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I have a small project here scanning for some mijia devices, works fine. Perhaps use that as inspiration. I cannot reproduce your issues. https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MijiaScanner/

Comment: Seems this has something to do with Android OS. https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/issues/104#issuecomment-363665550 I find that with my code it finds my required device sometimes, and does not find the device sometimes. In general after searching about 5 times, I am always able to find the Bluetooth device I am looking for. So maybe not an issue with the code or with the bluetoothLE module but more of an Android issue

Comment: @Kikanye can you share to us what Android version did you use?

Comment: Using version 7.1

Comment: for some newer Androids, there is a "feature" that you have to turn on GPS to find any devices

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a missing ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission for android.